# Extract vaues from an array in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm getting values of string in my response to whom i'm storing in an array. Its is storing properly.Now i want to get that values out of my array because later i have to add that in an another string to get their sum. My array looks like this, [0.5,0.5,0.5]. I have to extract all the 0.5 values and add them. I have tried a code it extract the values but in result it shows 0 value. My code is this,

```
let itemprice = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "itemPrice")
print(itemprice)
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "addonPrice") as? [Int] ?? [Int]() 
print(array)
let resultant = array.reduce(0, +)
print(resultant)
let result = itemprice! + String(resultant)
print(result)
```

i'm trying to add the arrays value to another value with the name itemprice. How can i get out all the values from my array and add them. The values in the array varies different time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it.. using `let array = [0.5,0.5,0.5]` and `let resultant = array.reduce(0, +)` I get `1.5`.. you are doing something else wrong

Comment: Please show *all* the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the value in itemprice?

Comment: What is `itemprice`? Is it a *number* or a *string*? In the code you posted, you are adding the ***String representation*** of `resultant` to `itemprice` -- which would indicate that `itemprice` is *also* a string. If it's not, that is where your problem lies.

Comment: @DonMag OP is claiming that the resultant is not working, returning value of `0`.. while the thing he does with `itemprice! + String(resultant)` is very very suspicious, it does not relate to his question

Comment: itemprice has value 4 and i want to add values in array to it. @surToTheW

Comment: itemprice has value 4 and i want to add values in array to it. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: Show the rest of the code

Comment: Is itemprice a number or a string. Which one is 0 - result or resultant?

Comment: itemprice is a string. when i got value in 'result' after adding itemprice and resultant it give me answer 40. @surToTheW

Comment: So resultant is a the 0. What is printed if you print(array) right before let resultant = array.reduce(0, +)

Comment: this is the code  let itemprice = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "itemPrice")
            print(itemprice)
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let array = defaults.array(forKey: "addonPrice")  as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
            print(array)
            let resultant = array.reduce(0, +)
            print(resultant)
            let result = itemprice! + String(resultant)
            print(result) . @MilanNosáľ

Comment: what does print(array) prints? moreover, you do realize that you cannot save value 0.5 as an Int, right?

Comment: i got [ ] in array when print it. @surToTheW

Comment: well then you are getting what you programmed.. it's an empty array, so adding its content to 0 is 0.. show the code where you store the data to `defaults.array(forKey: "addonPrice")`

Comment: Bro simple is that i have to add itemprice which is "4" to the items in an array , the array items varies, the items in an array are alse string like this, ["0.5","0.5"]. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: @Hamza why do you store that values as strings? store them as `Double`, to be able to work with them

Comment: @Hamza check update in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `0` as a result of `let resultant = array.reduce(0, +)` because in

```
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "addonPrice") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```

either the value stored in the defaults is an empty array, or the cast `as? [Int]` fails.

Considering you claim that the array is supposed to hold values `[0.5,0.5,0.5]` I assume that it is the latter case. `[0.5,0.5,0.5]` is an array of `Double` values, not `Int` values.

Try to fix it this way:

```
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "addonPrice") as? [Double] ?? [Double]()
```

**UPDATE**

From comments it seems that you are using strings everywhere, so then:

```
let itemprice = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "itemPrice")
print(itemprice)
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
// take it as an array of strings
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "addonPrice") as? [String] ?? [String]()
print(array)
// convert strings to Double
let resultant = array.map { Double($0)! }.reduce(0, +)
print(resultant)
let result = Double(itemprice!)! + resultant 
print(result)
```

Although I would **strongly** recommend you to work with `Double` from the beginning (both to store it and use it).

Comment: Yup gor it now thats the perfect one. Actually i'm getting values in string from backend that why i have to do so. @Milan Nosáľ

Comment: @Hamza so convert them once when you receive them so that you dont have to do it everytime you awnt to do something with them..